# Changing Background color of header and put stripped gray scale to rows kable

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, flextable

is there any way to change the header column and put the rows in grays (stripped style) by exteding the following code?

```
library(ReporteRs)
x = structure(c(34L, 6L, 9L, 35L), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    Actual = c("Fail", "Pass"), Predicted = c("Fail", "Pass")), .Names = c("Actual", 
"Predicted")), class = "table")

x=cbind(x, prop.table(x), prop.table(x, 1), prop.table(x,2))
x[, -c(1,2)] = sapply(x[,-c(1,2)], function(i) paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", i*100),"%"))
x = cbind(Actual=rownames(x), x)
cell_p = cellProperties(padding.right=3, padding.left=3)
par_p = parProperties(text.align="right")
ft = FlexTable(x, header.columns=FALSE, body.cell.props=cell_p, body.par.props=par_p)
ft = addHeaderRow(ft, text.properties=textBold(), c("","Predicted"),
                  colspan=c(1,8), par.properties=parCenter())

ft = addHeaderRow(ft, text.properties=textBold(), 
                  value=c("", "Count", "Overall\nPercent", "Row\nPercent", "Column\nPercent"),
                  colspan=c(1,rep(2,4)), par.properties=parCenter())

ft = addHeaderRow(ft, text.properties=textItalic(), par.properties=parCenter(),
                  value=colnames(x))
ft[1:2, 1, to="header", side="left"] = borderProperties(color="white")
ft[1:2, 1, to="header", side="top"] = borderProperties(color="white")

ft[3, 1, to="header"] = textProperties(font.style="normal", font.weight="bold")
ft[ , 1] = textProperties(font.style="italic")

ft[ , 2:3] = cellProperties(padding.right=7, padding.left=7)
ft[ , 1] = cellProperties(padding.right=10, padding.left=10)
ft
```

What we need is to put 1. Count, Overall Percent, Row Percent, Column Pecent cells with a blue background and white font.

2. and the rows 34 ... 20.5 %
   6 ... 79.5 %
   in a stripped gray background.
3. Do you think is there a way the frame lines of the table to another color? perhaps white so it gives an HTML like appearance.
   thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: you should use flextable and not use ReporteRs anymore, it's been 3 years it is archived and no more maintained.